# Bootstrap Accordian will not collapse with Electron but the HTML file will work fine outside of Electron

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, electron

I have two running examples both using the same HTML page here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="head">
            <th></th>
            <th>Skill</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Ranks</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Adjusted Total</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="content_1">
          <td><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#additional_row1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="additional_row1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></td>
          <td>Artistic</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=7 class="collapse" id="additional_row1">test</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I run this HTML code in a browser by itself, it works.

If i run this in Electron... it will not collapse once it has been expanded. I have no idea why Electron refuses to toggle it correctly.

for what it is worth here is my package.json for electron

```
{
  "name": "electronproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shopping List desktop app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Shopping List App\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "author": "David Klecker",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
     "jquery": "^3.5.0",
     "boostrap": "^2.0.0",
     "electron": "^8.2.0",
     "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
     "xml2js": "^0.4.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an issue with getting jQuery to work with Electron. If you have Node integration turned on in your renderer process, jQuery will have issues loading because of some conflicting symbols it tries to define.

There's more information in the [Electron FAQ](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/faq#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron).

The easiest way to solve this is to turn off `nodeIntegration` in your BrowserWindow.

```
// In the main process.
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: false
  }
})
```

If you want to keep `nodeIntegration` on, you could avoid the naming conflict by renaming the conflicting symbols before importing jQuery in.

```
<script>
window.nodeRequire = require;
delete window.require;
delete window.exports;
delete window.module;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

I'm able to get your code snippet to work properly with either of the above solutions on Electron `8.0.0`.

Comment: Thank you for proving to me that it works with electron. I finally figured out the issue. The issue was that I have bootstrap tabs and that I am using JQuery to load in a new page for each tab. The new page is a new html file which contained the Bootstrap libraries again. Having them in multiple times causes issues. Removing the bootstrap libraries from my html pages for tabs cleared the issue.